# Migrate Blogger Atom feed to self hosted blog

Tags: blogger, feeds

I have a blog running on blogger using my own domain (lets say `www.example.com`).
The standard blogger Atom feed is available at `www.example.com/feeds/posts/default`

Now I want to migrate my blog to a self hosted custom application without loosing atom feed subscribers. My new blog will also be available at `www.example.com`. The new atom feed is available at `www.example.com/feeds/atom`. I have full control over urls and the generation of the new atom feed.

I planned doing the following two things:

- Redirect (301) `www.example.com/feeds/posts/default` requests to `www.example.com/feeds/atom`
- Atom feed entries that have been migrated from the old blog will use the same `<id>` that has been used in the blogger atom feed. (I am not sure if this is necessary but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150741/how-do-you-generate-a-good-id-in-atom-documents), feed entry ids should not change)

Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: If you are in "full control over urls" then you could generate your atom feed at the same URL and not bother with the redirection? (Do all news readers follow redirection?) Alternatively, you could _internally rewrite_ the request from `/feeds/posts/default` to `/feeds/atom` - again, no need for a redirection?

Comment: You are right, I should probably rewrite the request internally to the new url, thanks.